# pip doesn't work even after add to environmental variable windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pip, environment-variables

I installed pip with get-pip.py, and it seemed that it was done successfully, and I added environmental variables. However, pip doesn't work (not recognized as internal or external command).

It doesn't work even if I write on the command line:
"C:\Users...\python-3.7.1-embed-amd64\Scripts\pip.exe" install numpy

I use windows 10, python 3.7, and i don't have admin rights. I edited user variables, also i asked admin to edit system environmental variables, but it didn't helped.

In case write path to pip.exe manually in the command line, it doesn't work as well.
(Pip and other expected files present in the Script folder!)

[env path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfAo3.png)

[pip install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIjCZ.png)

Comment: Have you re-launched cmd.exe after updating `PATH`?

Comment: You shouldn't be using the embedded version of Python (i.e. "python-3.7.1-embed-amd64"). Remove that and start over using the regular installer with a per-user installation, which will install pip and set up `PATH`.

Comment: yep, and even restarted laptop.

Comment: eryksun, thank you! Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

**To install packages, you need admin rights.**

1. Start "cmd" as administrator.
2. Write your command

**If you get error like:**

> Not recognized as internal or external command

if you get this error when you write "help" or other system commands, try start cmd using another way.

else, write not:

> pip install package

but:

> py -m pip install package

if you need python shell:

> py

Comment: The question is not about how to install python packages but how to make pip work.